# How to pick the specific variables in a dynamically generated facebook-like posts

Tags: php, sql, comments

i am retrieving posts from a table called post . I wanted to add a commenting feature to this code, i wanted the comments to be saved with the specific id of the post so that when retrieving, every comment is shown on the right post, but the problem is that if i comment on a post, it  only captures the details of the first post on the screen which is actually the last one posted because the retrieval is done on a ID DESC creteria..so every comment is being shown on the one/first post

```
<?php

    $sqlhash="SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC ";
        $result_hash = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlhash);
        while($rowhash = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result_hash))
        {
            $user = $rowhash['user'];
            $message = $rowhash['post'];
            $time =  $rowhash['time'];
        $id=  $rowhash['id'];
            $tt = date('m/d/Y H:i:s',$time);

    $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];




     $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Full_name='$user'  ";
      $result_set = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result_set))
      {

        $select_username = $row['Full_name'];
        $profp = $row['pic'];



    $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];











        ?>

<center><div class='post' style='width:48%; height:40%; align:middle; text-align:left; margin:30px 0'>
<img width="70" height="70" src='uploads/<?php echo $profp; ?>'><br><p style='color:#0c88b5'><b>  <?php echo $id ;?><br><?php echo $user ;?>On:<?php echo $tt ; ?><h4><b><?php echo $message 
;?></h4></p><hr>
<?php 

$sqlcom="SELECT * FROM comment WHERE hash='$id' ";
    $result_com = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlcom);
    while($rowcom = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result_com))
    {
        $usercom = $rowcom['comment'];
        $comenter = $rowcom['user'];

echo "<p style='color:#0c88b5' $comenter</p>". ":" ;
 echo $usercom. "<br>" ;

 }
if (isset($_POST['commen'])) {


$sqlhash= "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post= '$message' ";
    $result_hash = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlhash);
    while($rowhash = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result_hash))
    {
        $user1 = $_SESSION['username'];
        $comment = $_POST['commen'];
        $time =  $rowhash['time'];



        $time2 = $_SESSION['time'];



 $sql3 = "INSERT INTO comment (user, comment, hash) VALUES
             ('$user1','$comment', '$id')";

             if($conn->query($sql3) === TRUE) {

header('Location: timeline.php');

}else {
    echo"error";
}
```

Comment: That will take some time , let me see if i can give an example with a code

Comment: do you mind if i used PDO in my code ?

Comment: as long as it can work am fine

Comment: Cool give me few times so i can give you a clear answer . =)

Comment: do u have comments already in your database ? so you can test it ? can i have your comments table if that's ok

Comment: yes. how do i export it to you..it has 3 columns user, comment and comment_id

Comment: cool thx , you will add to that column called `comment_time` type will be datetime

Comment: ok. . then what next?

Comment: sorry another Q , you have column that called `id` in your comments table right and its primary key ? if yes then its all good , im almost done typing the code .

Comment: mhm had to read your Q again to get the problem and i just realized that i have the same issue with you sir , lol after typing for 20 just noticed that , the issue is that you have forms on the number of the posts in your table, and all of the forms have the same form id , so you have to create a dynamic id for each form , and thats what im trying to figure how to do . im really sorry

Comment: notify me if u get any success Laith

Comment: will do sir , still searching =) dont worry